# Tomcat error 404 not found while running a REST API

Tags: java, xml, rest, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I am trying to implement a very simple REST API in Eclipse.

Following is my project Structure:
[project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAokY.png)

**Hello.java:**

```
package test;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayHelloXML() {
        String responseString = "<? xml version='1.0' ?>" + 
                "<hello> Hello World XML</hello>";
        
        return responseString;
    }
    
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String sayHelloJSON() {
        String responseString = null;
        return responseString;
    }
    
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public String sayHelloHTML() {
        String responseString = "<h1> Hello World HTML</h1>";
        return responseString;
    }
}
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>JavaApiEdu</display-name>
  
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>JAVA API</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>test</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAVA API</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

To Run, I right-click on the project and choose Run on Server which is Tomcat 8.5.
I am unable to access this and see this page:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kDRp.png)

Comment: What do you see in your log files?

Comment: Where does `JavaApiEdu1` (from the error image) come from...?

Comment: @GyuHyeonChoi the JavaApiEdu1 is the project name in Eclipse

Comment: @tgdavies I see this one error:

Jan 19, 2021 10:22:21 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [JAVA API] in web application [/JavaApiEdu1] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.class
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1358)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling a lot there are generally small things that solve the issues.

I did two things:

1. I removed the .class from this servlet class name in my web.xml and it started working:
   [web.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmPNM.png)
2. I also gave a path to all my methods as GyuHyeon suggested. Although if I don't do this then also it's working after doing step 1. It will just go to one of the methods as opposed to a specific one. Giving path to each method is a good step to follow.

Note: to access the API the project name should be in the URL and not the package, so in my case, this worked: http://localhost:8080/JavaApiEdu1/hello/html

Thanks @GyuHyeonChoi & @tgdavies for replying.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have to specify `Path` for each `@GET`. E.g.,

```
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {

    @Path("xml")
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    ...
```

Then browse to `http://localhost:8080/test/rest/hello/xml`?

Comment: Hi @GyuHyeonChoi . I tried the solution you posted:

But I still get the same issue:
The requested resource [/test/rest/hello/xml] is not available

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your Tomcat version support proper JDK version.

I had the same problem, Tomcat deployed my app but when requesting GET there was 404 response. I have spent many hours on re-configuring code and Tomcat properties till I finally found the this simple reason. Tomcat 10.1.7 with JDK 17 works fine together.